# Python - Copiar Xpath de uma elemento de uma tabela grid usando Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

pessoal!

Estou criando um bot para baixar um pdf de um site. Usei o selenium para abrir o google chrome e consigo abrir a janela do site mas seleciono o Xpath do primeiro item do grid, mas não ocorre o clique para baixar o pdf. Acredito que estou obtendo o XPath errado.

Deixo o site que estou acessando e meu código abaixo. Você poderia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Estou obtendo o XPath correto? Muito obrigado antecipadamente.

O site em questão e do tribunal de contas do CE, são dados abertos e o pdf é diário.

[Site do tribunal de contas](https://www.tce.ce.gov.br/cidadao/diario-oficial-eletronico)
[Print do site e do elemento a ser clicado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5QRG.png)

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

try:
    navegador.get("https://www.tce.ce.gov.br/cidadao/diario-oficial-eletronico")
    time.sleep(2)

    navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formUltimasEdicoes:consultaAvancadaDataTable:0:j_idt101"]/input[1]').click()

    time.sleep(2)

    navegador.close()
    navegador.quit()

except:
    navegador.close()
    navegador.quit()
```

Comment: O XPath pego não está vinculado ao o botão de download parece que esta para submit, acho que esse pode ser o correto: `(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formUltimasEdicoes:consultaAvancadaDataTable:0:j_idt101"]/a').click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, amigo!

Consegui resolver o problema e eis o que entendi :
Se utilizarmos o Beautiful Soup para ter acesso ao Html da página, perceberemos que os elementos que precisamos interagir estão dentro de um html dentro de um iframe, não diretamente na página e por isso não conseguimos acessá-los convencionalmente.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
pagina = navegador.page_source
site = BeautifulSoup(pagina,"html.parser")
print(site.prettify())
```

Dentro desse print tu vai conseguir perceber isso :

```
> <iframe frameborder="0" height="1000" id="blockrandom" name="iframe" scrolling="no" src="https://doe-consulta.tce.ce.gov.br/doeconsulta/paginas/consulta-textual-ou-data-edicao-do.xhtml" width="100%">
```

Se tu copiar o link de src numa nova aba, vai conseguir abrir a parte da página que quer interagir, ou seja, precisamos que o navegador/selnium "olhe" para aquele html de src.

Dito isso, seu código final fica dessa forma :

```
try:
    navegador.get("https://www.tce.ce.gov.br/cidadao/diario-oficial-eletronico")
    time.sleep(2)

    iframe = navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'iframe#blockrandom') #define variavel para o iframe
    navegador.switch_to.frame(iframe) # faz o navegador "olhar" para o iframe

    lista_botoes = navegador.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.imagemBotao')
    lista_botoes[0].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    navegador.close()
    navegador.quit()
except:
    navegador.close()
    navegador.quit()
```